# SSD failiure. grub rescue sees files, but I can't mount drives

Tags: grub2, hard-disk, data-recovery, ext4

I have a 2 year old SSD that apparently has died. 2 out of the 3 partitions are completely unmountable (only EFI boot partition mountable). When i turn on my computer I am greeted with `grub rescue` prompt where I can list the directories of my 2 unmountable partitions and see that (most) files are there.

However when I get a live usb in I can't mount any of the two ext4 drives.

When i try to use

```
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/tmp
```

I get an error

`btrfs parent transit verify failed on  n, wanted m found m+18
open_ctree failed
wrong FS type`

where n is some sector and m is some transaction number. My filesystem is not btrfs but ext4, when I try `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb2 /mnt/tmp` I get:

`VFS: can't find ext4 filesystem`

I get the same when I try to run `fsck.ext4`. I tried specifying a new superblock but they all seem to be not working. It claims that I doesn't see an `ext4` filesystem.

My questions: How does `grub rescue` see my hard drive and can list the files when I can't mount it? Does it mean that information is salvageable?

Why are my `ext4` drives detected as `btrfs`?

Any ideas how to try to get my data?

Comment: If the device itself is bad, you should probably start with `ddrescue`.

Comment: I am not sure if the device itself is bad, this is just my suspicion since two filesystems failed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Testdisk helped me more than once. It will search for filesystem and/or files. Give it a try:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: Thanks! I am unfortunately away from my machine but I had not heard of that software. I will try it when I am back close to it.

Comment: Doesn't work :/ doesn't recognize the filesystem at all

Comment: That's bad news.  Have you worked with their instructions? You may be able to save some files with photorec (part of the same suit). If both programs fail to find anything I'm afraid the only option left for you is a professional service.

Comment: When I try to list filesystem files it doesn't find anything, so I don't think it would help...

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu photorec can rescue files in cases where the filesystem can't be recognized. If tiy have important data files in there, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. I have changed my harddrive and I will get a dock to try to read the old one.